# Errors in passing data in PHP.

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

Hi guys i have errors right now, i don't understand why this errors come up, can you point to me the problem guys? thanks. this are the errors:

**

```
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at com.example.projectthesis.Register.validation(Register.java:55)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at com.example.projectthesis.Register$1.onClick(Register.java:49)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-29 20:14:46.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1827):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**

and this are my codes:

**

```
public class Register extends Activity {
    EditText inputFname;
    EditText inputLname;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    EditText inputCpassword;
    EditText inputCellno;
    Button btnRegister;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        inputFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFname);
        inputLname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLname);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
        inputCpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCpassword);
        inputCellno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCellno);

        Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        // button click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                validation();
            }
        });
    }
    public void validation() {
        if (inputFname.getText().toString().equals("") || inputLname.getText().toString().equals("") || inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")
                || inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("") || inputCpassword.getText().toString().equals("") || inputCellno.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill Empty Fields",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            new phpconnect().execute();
        }
    }
    class phpconnect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", inputFname
                    .getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", inputLname
                    .getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eadd", inputEmail
                    .getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", inputPassword
                    .getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cpassword", inputCpassword
                    .getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cellno", inputCellno
                    .getText().toString()));
            // Passing Parameter to the php web service for authentication
            // String valid = "1";
            String response = null;
            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient
                        .executeHttpPost(
                                "http://10.0.2.2/TheCalling/index.php",
                                postParameters); // Enter Your remote PHP,ASP,
                                                    // Servlet
                                                    // file link
                // error.setText(res);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "0";
            }
            return response;
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
            String res = result.toString();
            String num = "1";
            res = res.trim();
            res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            if (res.equals(num)) {
                // Display Toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Correct Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**

This errors happens after clicking my button, and if you want my php codes, here it is:

**

```
<?php
include("db_config.php");
$fname=($_POST['fname']);
$mname=($_POST['mname']);
$lname=($_POST['lname']);
$eadd=($_POST['eadd']);
$password=($_POST['password']);
$cpassword=($_POST['cpassword']);
$cellno=($_POST['cellno']);
$sql="INSERT INTO `users` SET `fname`='{$_POST['fname']}', `lname`='{$_POST['lname']}', `eadd`='{$_POST['eadd']}', `password`='{$_POST['password']}', `cpassword`='{$_POST['cpassword']}', `cellno`='{$_POST['cellno']}'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
    {
    echo "1";
    //(If result found send 1 to android)
    }
else
    {
    echo "0";
    //(If result not found send o to android)
    }
?>
```

**

Comment: The error message is indicating that you have a `null` object when executing your `validation()` method in your `Register` class. Prior to the code being executed, what are the values for the specific variables you are checking against in your `if` statement?

Comment: well, i think i'm trying to check if the input fields is equal to space.

Comment: Are the values of those variables actually defined prior to comparing the values? If one of those variables do not exist, that could be the source of your `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

A `NullPointerException` means that you tried to access an method or property of `null`.

According to the stacktrace the cause of this is here:

```
if (
    inputFname.getText().toString().equals("")
   || inputLname.getText().toString().equals("") 
   || inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")
   || inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("") 
   || inputCpassword.getText().toString().equals("") 
   || inputCellno.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    //Some other code
}
```

Something in there is null, probably one (or some) or the input variables. It's worth taking some time to print out what these values are, until you find the null that's causing it.